# Ajax não reconhece o echo do PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Tenho um ajax simples:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"php/exemplo.php",
    type:"POST", 
    data:new FormData(this),
    contentType:false,
    cache:false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(resposta){
      if(resposta == '<nome>'){
        alert('deu certo');
      }
}});
```

No PHP eu dou um `echo "<nome>";` e esse `<nome>` chega no ajax certinho (chequei com um alert)... mas o if não entende que é `<nome>`, não cai dentro do if...

O que pode ser o erro?

Comment: O que dá `console.log(typeof resposta, resposta && resposta.length, resposta);`?

Comment: Talvez esteja com espaço, use a função `trim()` do php

Comment: Posta o PHP, siga sempre o MCVE (Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: O PHP é apenas um echo "nome";

Comment: @GeekSilva com trim faria assim? echo trim("<nome>");? Se for, não deu tb....

Comment: @Sergio realmente esse console.log deu 8.. e não 6 como deveria dar

Comment: @caiocafardo ok, então tem espaços em branco presumo ou quebras de linha. Testa assim: `if(resposta.trim() == '<nome>'){`. Se não der coloca o resultado exato de console.log que pedi em cima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro era o que estavam falando, estava vindo algum espaço vazio do PHP. Consegui ajustar usando o trim do Jquery: [jQuery.trim()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

Ficando assim:

```
if($.trim(resposta) == '<nome>'){
```

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente o retorno do Ajax esteja vindo com algum espaço ou quebra de linha junto com `<nome>`, por isso o `if` entende que resposta não é **exatamente** `<nome>`.

Uma forma de solucionar isso é mudando a forma de comparação com `indexOf`:

```
if(resposta.indexOf('<nome>') != -1){
  alert('deu certo');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar o `.trim()` nativo do JavaScript e fazer `if(resposta.trim() == '<nome>'){`.

Assim limpas espaços em branco e quebras de linha antes da comparação.

Answer (score -1):

Certifique-se que o `<nome>` obtido no AJAX não tem nenhum espaço a mais antes ou depois s e se está utilizando UTF-8 sem BOM.